# Proper way to use multiple js file

Tags: javascript

I made long 2d game JavaScript file. I would like to divide it to multiple js file for each level so it will be easier to understand it and maintain it.

Is it possible to trigger a function from a js file that lies in another file? My thought is just to link to `level_one` script in html, and once the `level_one` is done, it will call the function in `level_two` script. Like a chain reaction/link.

I'm starting the game by

```
<body onload="startGame()">
```

Comment: yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: @traktor53 Oh I thought it would be more advanced. 
Just to be sure as I'm learning, is this a good way to keep js code organized, or should I consider other ways?

Comment: My suggestion is to review documentation of script tags to load external files and try simple examples to ensure calls between multiple files are working. Separating the code into different files may well be of benefit but remains a matter of choice and opinion - I would leave exploring advanced alternatives until after you are more comfortable with script files in general.

Comment: You can call functions that are declared in other javascript files. You just need to import both files in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes!

**Long answer:** there are *many* ways this is done, there are many libraries, frameworks, and paradigms people use. Maybe a good place for you to start would be to search for ways to include multiple files using pure JS. Start with small experiments. Have fun learning and good luck!